# PHP only displays MySQL data if more than one row fits criteria

Tags: php, database, mysqli

## **OVERVIEW:**

So, I'm working on a sort of "search script" to help users find data based upon 2 different types of data. They can search by *Category* or by *Encoding* grabbed from my database.

### Problem:

The array only returns 1 row, while there are 3 (exact) duplicates in my database, problem still occurs if the entries are different.

### Code Snippet:

```
<?php
$catagory = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['c']);
$encode = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['e']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE ";
if(!empty($catagory)) {
$query =$query . "catagory = '$catagory'" ;
}
if(!empty($encode)) {
    if(!empty($catagory)) {
        $query = $query . " AND " ;
    }
    $query = $query. "urlencode = '$encode'" ;
}

$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if (empty($row)) {
    $message = "Sorry, there were no results";
    echo $message;
} ELSE {
    echo '<table>';
    echo '<thead>';
    echo '<th>Title</th><th>Posted</th><th>Address</th><th>Views</th>';
    echo '</thead>';
    echo '<tbody>';
    $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $title = htmlspecialchars($row['titlepre']);
        echo $row['titlepre'];
        $posted = dateDiff($row['date'],$now);
        $address = $row['address'];
        $views = $row['views'];
        $url = $row['url'];
        echo '<tr><td><a href ="'.$url.'">'.$title.'</a></td><td>'.$posted.'</td><td>'.$address.'</td><td>'.$views.'</td></tr>';
    }
    echo '</tbody>';
    echo '</table>';
}
?>
```

### Database Information

```
| ID | address  | title | titlepre | content |   Catagory     |  url  | urlencode | views |  date
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 3  |[WITHHELD]| title |  title   | content | Rants - Things | HDyLkl | Scheme   |   1   |2013-11-28 |
| 5  |[WITHHELD]| title |  title   | content | Rants - Things | HDyLkl | Scheme   |   1   |2013-11-28 |
```

Now, I'm fairly new to PHP, so please bear with me if my code isn't 100% efficient.

Comment: Side note: Why do you have both a database connection with `mysql` and `mysqli`? Why don't you use prepared statements instead if using `mysqli`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every use of *mysqli_fetch_array* shifts off the record from the results set.

You have checking for results:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

So that first record of *$results* is being "deleted".

```
do{
    $title = htmlspecialchars($row['titlepre']);
    echo $row['titlepre'];
    $posted = dateDiff($row['date'],$now);
    $address = $row['address'];
    $views = $row['views'];
    $url = $row['url'];
    echo '<tr><td><a href ="'.$url.'">'.$title.'</a></td><td>'.$posted.'</td><td>'.$address.'</td><td>'.$views.'</td></tr>';
}while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
```

Should be working.

But move to the PDO/mysqli objective. They have an iterator.